# Strange logout issues on clicking icons in the launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, logout

I have a fresh install of 14.04.2 and whenever I open more than one window of a program (for example, two windows of chrome, or nautilus), and click the icon on the unity launcher, the system shuts down all my processes and logs me out. This only happens on clicking, not when I access things another way (for example, Alt-Tab-ing to the window works).

This only happens when clicking the program which already has more than one window running, I can launch programs and switch between processes which only have one window by clicking.

I tried a couple of simple things like reinstalling `unity-control-center`, and `lightdm`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems to be a known Unity bug related to 'Window Spread' setting:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1462841?comments=all

The workaround is to disable 'Windows Spread' (thus losing that feature until the bug is fixed). Lame, but at the moment I'm not aware of anything better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Uninstalling unity-tweak-tool removed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get purge unity-tweak-tool
```